# Arduino HTTP request loop fails after first loop

Tags: c#, http, arduino

im trying to make a HTTP request loop, however, it seems to fail after the first time. i have no idea why this is happening, ive had a look around online and it's something to do with closing the request and then restarting it(i think), but i cant seem to do it?

my loop code is available here http://pastie.org/4199450

i get the following when i run it:

SUCCESS!
connection failed
connection failed
..

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to the server/port once without disconnecting after.

Then, you try to connect again but you are still connected. This may be the reason why the connection line fail the second times.

Comment: something like else if (client.connected()==true) {
      disconnect(); ?

Comment: stil getting the problem even when adding client.close(), can anyone show me how to properly implement it